# Incomparable types: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends T[]> and java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object[]>

Tags: java, casting

I was trying to understand casting in java while I was playing with a few methods inside the Arrays Class.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and in the following method

```
public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
        ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
        : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

in the following line:

```
T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
```

IDE suggests that casting to (Object) is redundant.

Removing the casting is causing the following error.

```
Incomparable types: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends T[]> and java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object[]>
```

which made me thing that at first the error is correct, but experimenting for a while made me realise that I did not understand the issue because refactoring the code like ->

```
T[] copy = (newType == (Object)Object[].class)
```

and

```
T[] copy = ((Object)newType == Object[].class)
```

does **NOT** produce this error.

I cannot figure out why it does not produce this error, could someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

The incomparable types error is telling you that it doesn't make sense to compare two things that cannot possibly be equal.

For example, there's no point in `Integer.valueOf(0) == ""`, because they're not the same types; nor is one a supertype of the other. It will always be false.

The compiler will prevent the `a == b` if both are class types (as opposed to interfaces), and both `a = b` and `b = a` would be disallowed.

So, you are being told that a `Class<? extends T[]>` cannot be equal to a `Class<Object[]>`, because you can't assign a reference of one type to a variable of the other type.

By casting one of the references to `Object`, the compiler no longer knows (/thinks) that the types are definitely not related - because `Object` is a supertype of everything, so "nor is one a supertype of the other" is no longer true - so the compiler allows the check.

---

One thing that *is* redundant in that method is `U`. There's no need for it, just use `Object[]` in the parameter type instead.

Comment: `One thing that is redundant in that method is U. There's no need for it, just use Object[] in the parameter type instead.` - Are you suggesting to change the JDK? The method the OP posted is taken from `java.util.Arrays` class.

Comment: @Eran Are you suggesting it's necessary? I'm not really suggesting the JDK should be changed, but since OP is asking what different bits do, it's worth saying you wouldn't need it if you were starting again.

Comment: I didn't say that, but if you are suggesting a change in  a JDK method, I think you are the one who should explain/justify such a change.

Comment: @AndyTurner could you explain `you can't assign a reference of one type to a variable of the other type.`

Comment: `The compiler will prevent the a == b`  ----> Do you mean that if I try `((T)newType == (U)Object[].class)` the compiler will prevent it?