# Operator '==' cannot be applied...(java)

Tags: java, object

I'm, having a little problem understanding why I get this compiler error. This was just a way for me to understand how all reference type inherit from Object class, but I'm more lost than ever :(

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class InheritObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InheritObject().program();
    }

    void program() {
        MyOwnClass m = new MyOwnClass();

        out.println(m.toString());
        out.println(m.getClass());   // Get class used to create this object
        out.println(m.equals("abc"));  // m == "abc" not allowed, but equals is!
        out.println(m=="abd");      // ... and default equals() uses == ?!
        out.println(m.equals(5));
        out.println(m.hashCode());
        // Etc.

    }

    class MyOwnClass{
        // No methods here!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the exact compiler output in your question. In any case the error happens because the Java compiler *knows* that `m`, being an instance of `MyOwnClass`, will never be `==` to `"abcd"` (a `java.lang.String`), while it is possible to write an `equals` method which will consider them equal (even if that violates the "contract" of `equals`).

Comment: I think @AndyTurner has also provided a nice answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60136054/6367213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `equals` exists on all `Object` instances and permits any other `Object` (or `null`)  to be passed. `m.equals("abc")` is therefore okay; it meets the (very loose) requirements of `equals`.

This is allowed because one could write an `equals` method that indeed *does* allow an `MyOwnClass` instance to be equal to a `String` instance. (It's probably not a *good* idea, but something *technically valid*.)

`==` is different. It has a very specific meaning when dealing with reference types. It returns `true` if and only if the two arguments are the exact same instance; `false` otherwise.

However, in this case, when comparing an `MyOwnClass` and a `String`, the compiler knows that that comparison *can never ever be true* since the two provably don't inherit from each other. There is no situation where this comparison would make sense or even be useful; the developer must have made a mistake.

If you still *want* to make this comparison nonetheless, you can cast one or both of the arguments to `Object`:

```java
out.println(m == (Object) "abd");
```

The comparison is now between a `MyOwnClass` and an `Object`. Since `MyOwnClass` inherits from an `Object`, a `someMyOwnClass == someObject` could sometimes be `true`, so the comparison is permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Read here please https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.

Answer (score 0):

== is an operator to compare the reference values and objects.
equals() is used to compare the actual content of the object.

you can also check this post:
[What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java)